# What does the interface function/"cast" actually do in golang?

Tags: go

I'm relatively new to golang, and the project I'm looking at has this sort of pattern repeated several times:

```
package foo

type Foo interface {
    Bar() int
}

type foo struct {
}

func (f *foo) Bar() int {
    return 42
}

func New() Foo {
    // why?
    return Foo(&foo{})
}
```

If I replace the returns statement in the last function with `return &foo{}` everything works fine as I expected... it's duck typing if I understand it correctly.  So what is the point of using the Foo(...) function?  Using a type as a function seems to work when you're wrapping a built in type such as int in a type that probably has methods.  I'm curious as to the author's intent here.  If it's covered in the language spec I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression Foo(x) is a [conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). The conversion is not needed here because a `*foo` is [assignable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) to a `Foo`. The code should be written as:

```
func New() Foo {
  return &foo{}
}
```